# How to simplify $\frac{-y^2}{(y^2-yx)^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to simplify $\large{\frac{-y^2}{(y^2-yx)^2}}$?

Here's what I have done:

$= \large{\frac{-y^2}{(y^2-yx)(y^2-yx)}}$

$= \large{\frac{-y^2}{(y-x)y(y-x)y}}$

$= \large{\frac{-y^2}{y^2(y-x)(y-x)}}$

$= \large{\frac{-1}{(y-x)(y-x)}}$

$= \large{\frac{-1}{(y-x)^2}}$

Have I simplified it correctly?

Comment: Yes, the simplification is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you did correctly. Another way is
$$\frac{-y^2}{(y^2-yx)^2}=-\left(\frac{y}{y^2-yx}\right)^2=-\left(\frac{1}{y-x}\right)^2=-\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do the following:
$$-\frac{y^2}{(y^2 - yx)^2} = -\frac{y^2}{\big(y(y-x)\big)^2} = -\frac{y^2}{y^2(y-x)^2} = -\frac{1}{(y-x)^2},\ y\neq 0, y\neq x$$